# How should I use a timer in this method?

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

I am an apprentice for application development, and for a school project I need to develop a simulation for an elevator. I made some buttons that will drive to the destination I want. But to make it more realistic, I want to implement a timer with a 200ms interval.

```
private void EtagenWahl(int gewuenschteEtage)
    {
        var ziel = gewuenschteEtage;
        var a1 = Schacht1.Value;
        var a2 = Schacht2.Value;
        var a3 = Schacht3.Value;

        var differenz_a1 = Math.Abs(ziel - a1);
        var differenz_a2 = Math.Abs(ziel - a2);
        var differenz_a3 = Math.Abs(ziel - a3);

        if (differenz_a1 < differenz_a2 && differenz_a1 < differenz_a3)
        {
           Schacht1.Value = gewuenschteEtage;
        }
        else if (differenz_a2 < differenz_a3 && differenz_a2 < differenz_a1)
        {
            Schacht2.Value = gewuenschteEtage;               
        }
        else if (differenz_a3 < differenz_a1 && differenz_a3 < differenz_a2)
        {
            Schacht3.Value = gewuenschteEtage;     
        }
        if (differenz_a1 == differenz_a2)
        {
            Schacht1.Value = gewuenschteEtage;   
        }
        else if (differenz_a2 == differenz_a3)
        {
            Schacht2.Value = gewuenschteEtage;
        }
        else if (differenz_a1 == differenz_a3)
        {
            Schacht1.Value = gewuenschteEtage;
        }
    }

    private void Gast1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EtagenWahl(0);   
    }
```

I am sorry that the code is written in German, but I think that should not be a problem here. The question is, where and how should I put a timer?

Ps. This is just a bit of the code, if you need more, I can post it.

Comment: "i want to implement a timer with a 200ms interval" You haven't told us what you want this timer to do. Is it a latency after pressing the button? Does it drive an "animation" of the elevator's position?

Comment: am I right to assume, you want to delay the execution of EtagenWahl() ? in this case you dont need a timer but instead for example a Thread.Sleep()

Comment: Well, i tried to implement Thread.Sleep(), but to be honest, i don't know where i should put it in there